# is there a way to query and map datas with their correspondance in laravel

Tags: laravel

How to map data from one table to may other data from other  table;
example we have three table region, market, categories, products using eloquent in laravel 5.1
i have tried this but only gives me the last

```
public function look(Request $request)
{
    ``$sector_id=$request->input('category');
 $cells=Cell::where('sector_id',"=",$sector_id)->get();

 foreach ($cells as $cell){
    $a=$cell->id;
    $markets=Market::where('cell_id',"=",$a)->get();
}
 foreach ($markets as $market){
    $b=$market->id;
    $prices=Price::where('market_id',"=",$b)->get();
}
```

return view('reports.sector')->with('cells',$cells)->with('markets',$markets)-`>with('prices',$prices);
}

i need to display only the names in above table but what i need is that one elements in each table maps with their corresponding elements from other table how can i do that query.i need all of those data from database  please help me i am stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean three separate tables:

```
$cells = Cell::where('sector_id', $sector_id)->get();
$markets = Market::whereIn('cell_id', $cells->pluck('id'))->get();
$prices = Price::whereIn('market_id', $markets->pluck('id'))->get();
```

If you want to display the data in a tree-like structure, and if you have defined your model [relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships) properly you can use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

`$cells = Cell::where('sector_id', $sector_id)->with('markets.prices')->get()`

Pass `cells` to the view and you can use the following in your blade template to display the data

```
@foreach ($cells as $cell)
  @foreach ($cell->markets as $market)
    @foreach ($market->prices as $price)
```